# How can i plot Fourier transform of a wav without using FFT

Tags: matlab, debugging

How can I plot the Fourier transformation of a `wav` sound without using `FFT`?
I take rectangle windows with size `256` on the whole signal.

Following is my code:

**My code:**

```
[wave,fs]=wavread('.\Sound clip 32.wav');

sound(wave,fs); 

t=1:1/fs:length(wave)-1/fs;

plot(t,wave);

n=length(wave)-1; 

for l=1:n,

    x(l)=0;
end

for i=1:n,
     for h=1:256,
        x(i)=x(i)+wave(h)*(exp(-(j*2*pi*i*h)/n));
     end
end

f=1:fs/n:n;

wavefft=abs(x); 

plot(f,wavefft);
```

but I get this error

**Error:**

> ??? Error using ==> plot
>       Vectors must be the same lengths.
>
> Error in ==> alirezabahrami at 8 plot(t,wave);

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: To begin with, what are the `size`s of `f` and `wavefft`?

Comment: I bet you confused the order of operations - it should be `(length(wave)-1)/fs` - note the brackets. but actually `1+length(wave)/fs` would make more sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first plot error is caused by `t` and `wave` being different lengths. You could truncate the longest of those two and then plot, but in any case, `t` is simply a linearly increasing vector, so you can just write

```
plot (wave)
```

and it will display the same thing, ie., your audio wave.
If you write `plot(t)` you will just get a diagonal line.

further down you have the exact same problem, so just write:

```
plot(wavefft)
```